# File Not Found after File Picked

Tags: java, android, filepath, filenotfoundexception, filepicker

First, I would like to apologize if this is a simplistic error. I'm mostly self taught, what I know is incredibly sporadic, and could well be haphazard.

I'm working on an app which works as a password manager. It has a backup and restore function. I got it to work using a fixed directory with no issues, but upon attempting to add a File Picker, there have been issues.

The file location is saved with no issues. Then, one line after it verifies that it was saved, it says the file doesn't exist. Here is the relevant code as well as the error log. I only will include the code up into the crash, what follows is irrelevant but can be provided if asked. PSync.psbk is the file attempting to be read. Frankly, no idea what's wrong, but I assume it's simple.

Code:

```
 Toast.makeText(Main.this, "Method properly called.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //The file variable to imported.
                File file;

                try {
                    //Sets the file equal to the file found at the specified path.
                    //Used to access settings.
                    TinyDB database = new TinyDB(getApplicationContext());

                    String strfilePath = database.getString("FilePath");
                    Toast.makeText(Main.this, "Method properly called: " + strfilePath, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    file = new File(strfilePath);

                    //To be used to arrange the imported information.
                    ArrayList<String> strAcc = new ArrayList<>();
                    ArrayList<String> strUser = new ArrayList<>();
                    ArrayList<String> strPass = new ArrayList<>();
                    ArrayList<String> strAdditionalInfo = new ArrayList<>();

                    //To be used to store all the information for additional info variables. This is
                    //due to its multi-line nature requiring a slightly different method of 
                    //importation, the other variables are expected to be one line.
                    String strExtraInfo = "";

                    //Goes through the file and adds info to arrays for each corresponding variable.
                    //If the line does not have an identifier, it assumes it to be an additional
                    //info line, and will be processed later.
                    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {  //Line 776, as mentioned in err log.
```

Err log:

```
 W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /document/storage/emulated/0/Download/PSync.psbk (No such file or directory)
    10-04 21:16:32.843 19405-19405/com.example.brand.psync W/System.err:     at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    10-04 21:16:32.843 19405-19405/com.example.brand.psync W/System.err:     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
    10-04 21:16:32.843 19405-19405/com.example.brand.psync W/System.err:     at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:72)
    10-04 21:16:32.843 19405-19405/com.example.brand.psync W/System.err:     at com.example.brand.psync.Main.onRequestPermissionsResult(Main.java:776)
```

Comment: have you given permission in manifest

Comment: Yes I have, and it asks for runtime permission as well. It has no issue reading the file when it is in the format of   file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "PSync.psbk");

Comment: @NabinBhandari, yes this code snippet is inside onRequestPermissionsResult. The code only runs once the permission has been granted. As I told Amrutha, it has no issue reading the same file from the same directory when I use the Environmemnt.get method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path you are trying to access is:

> /document/storage/emulated/0/Download/PSync.psbk

There should not be leading **/document** in your path. There might be a problem while storing the path.

Comment: Just to clarify before I test, what should the path look like? /storage/emulated/0/Download/PSync.psbk ?

Comment: After you said that, I decided to test something because I thought it was weird. I get the file path by broadcasting the intent and having them use a file manager. For some odd reason, my main file browser returned it as "/document/storage/emulated/0/Download/PSync.psbk", but using a different file browser returned the correct path and allowed it to work. Since this wasn't an error in the code, how should I handle answering this question? Just check yours right? Or delete it since it wasn't related to the code?

Comment: I found where the mistake was lying. I think there's no harm in marking my answer as accepted. ;)

Comment: Fair enough lol Thanks, by the way. Would have never thought to try another file browser, I need sleep.